# What does "Costa Rica" in Intel CPU mean?

Tags: intel-core-i5

What does "Costa Rica" inscription on an Intel CPU mean? I have an i5-2400 and it has this text on its body (among other data). Is this some codename for a certain CPU-modification or just a place where this model was developed/produced?

Comment: It's the country of manufacture, as a simple Google search would have found.

Comment: @AFH I wouldn't ask here if "a simple google search" had found something. A simple google search has only found job opportunities at Intel's in Costa Rica.

Comment: @AFH It's the **packaging** site, not the **manufacturing site**, according to Patrick Mahoney Microprocessor Design Engineer Intel Corp, as a simple google search would have found ("intel cpu costa rica" first result) ;)

Comment: It is worth pointing out.  I actually performed a Google search using "intel cpu costa rica" as the search query.  One result if you read it, would made you believe Costa Rica was indeed a manufacturing site, since they basically said the "first batch from Malasian sucked".  Although I agree the actual first result is pretty clear even if its an official unofficial statement ( due to not actually being on Intel's website ).  Of course tomshardware ( the second result ) is the absolutely worst website for technical information.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I stand corrected. I found the TomsHardware site (using `"intel i5" "costa rica"`) and didn't read the entry fully. Mea culpa.

Comment: @Ramhound A post by someone who says he is "Patrick Mahoney Microprocessor Design Engineer Intel Corp." is good enough for me ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill - I could change my username here to `Bill Gates` does not mean I am actually Bill Gates.  Which is the reason I indicate it was an official unofficial statement.

Comment: @Ramhound <Shrug> He's been an Intel employee for more than 20 years according to his linked-in profile.

Comment: @Ramhound http://ewh.ieee.org/r5/denver/sscs/2005_03_Montecito.html "Patrick Mahoney is a Staff Engineer at Intel and works on the Itanium family of processors in the Digital Enterprise Group where his focus has been on high-speed digital circuit design.  He joined Intel in 1995 and worked on the cache design of Intel's Pentium microprocessor.  In 1997, he moved to Fort Collins, CO, and joined the Itanium 2 microprocessor team working on circuitry for the L1 data cache for the first Itanium 2 codenamed McKinley."

Comment: I don't actually doubt that is Patrick Mahoney.  I mean you have to be actually worthless as a human being, to pretend to be somebody as random, as a random Staff Engineer from Intel.  My comment really was pointing out that Tomshardware is useless as a source because it is full of invalid information so it can't be used as a technical source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### What does "Costa Rica" inscription on an Intel CPU mean?

> Is this some codename for a certain CPU-modification or just a place where this model was developed/produced?

The markings on the back of the CPU refer to the packaging site, not the manufacturing site of the actual silicon chip

---

#### Intel CPU Markings (ie. Malay vs. Costa Rica)

> Just to clear something up, the markings on the back of the CPU refer
> to the packaging site - not the manufacturing site of the actual
> silicon chip itself.
>
> Intel has no fabs in either Malaysia or Costa
> Rica, they are packaging facilities. The silicon die/chips are
> manufactured elsewhere in the world and are shipped to either of these
> two packaging sites.
>
> In addition, Intel manufacturing has a goal of
> running a "virtual fab" - meaning that, among other things, products
> from one fab are statistically indistinguishable from those
> manufactured at another fab.
>
> So even if, for example using fake names,
> Malaysian packages used chips only from fab #1 and packages marked
> Costa Rica use chips from fab #2, there should be no difference
> statistically between these two.

...

> Patrick Mahoney Microprocessor Design Engineer Intel Corp.

Source [Intel CPU Markings (ie. Malay vs. Costa Rica)](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=750461)

Answer (score 1):

Intel Costa Rica was a manufacturing plant, not just a simple packaging site, since 1998 until 2014 when the corporation decided it was too expensive to manufacture in the country.

The shipping costs were incredibly high because of the country’s lack of infrastructure, and the social charges were very high for manufacturing in comparison with other countries. They fired around 1500 “blue collar workers”.

Most people believed they were going to totally shut down the plant and leave the country, but thanks to the government negotiations the renovated the plant in a testing facility and experimental laboratory. A year later they began hiring all sorts of engineers. Nowadays they actually have more white collar workers than ever before.

Sources:

1. http://www.elfinancierocr.com/negocios/hecho-Intel-Costa-Rica-anos_10_496250371.html
2. http://www.reuters.com/article/us-intel-costa-rica-idUSBREA371TJ20140409